# Is there a programatic way to deal with subform / scrollbar situations in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, scroll, scrollbar, horizontalscrollview

[image: subform 'frm_Stage' window limiation]

SHORT DESCRIPTION:  I need to see all the columns in a datasheet subform. Specifically - 12 columns of months.  To do that, I need a horizontal scroll bar.  To get to that scroll bar is a challenge. I am developing in MS Access 2007.

THOROUGH DESCRIPTION:
I have a subform 'frm_SP' which displays in datasheet view that is 22" wide which is limit in width for a form - it is nested in another subform called 'frm_stage'.

I finally discovered that no matter how wide I make the very top "Parent form - 'frm_Entry' I can't seem to make ALL of this 3rd nested subform 'frm_SP' visible. The horizontal bar at the bottom just seems to compensate by proportionately growing to keep the limitation intact - this is frustrating.

As you can see in this image below, I have to scroll down to see the horizontal scroll bar.  Why is it so far down? Did I specify that somewhere?  It keeps that distance no matter how many records exist in the datasheet.  So if it only had 4 records, I'd still have to scroll all the way down to see the scroll bar. 
Similarly, I have a set of records that go beyond the horizontal scroll bar and I have no way of making the window large enough to see those records.  So I have had to tell the client to open the actual table if they need to edit those records.

I have hesitated to post anything like this because it requires images, but now that I have done the work, hopefully this can solve a lot of issues for other users.  Maybe this is the reason that there aren't many answers on the web that I can find.

Any tips, suggestions for alternate methods are welcome.

[image: unnecessary space below the last record in the datasheet of frm_SP]

I added "SendKeys" code for the arrow keys so that that the 12 boxes would function more like a spreadsheet. 
But I don't understand why January is skipped and then it continues to skip every 2 boxes

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub txtDEC_NC_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
 Select Case KeyCode
        Case 40 'down
            SendKeys "{TAB}", False

        Case 38 'up
            SendKeys "+{TAB}", False

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Any chance you can post a screenshot to show what you mean?

Comment: Yes.  I have edited my post and added 2 images annotated and described to illustrate my dilemma.

Comment: Okay, just to make sure I understand the issue.  Your third nested form is the datasheet, which extends further than is needed.  This is causing your second nested form to expand down to compensate, therefore allowing the datasheet form's horizontal scroll to move below the view of the second nested form which is the cause of the unnecessary vertical scroll.   Does this sound about right?   If so what is the height property of your datasheet form?

Comment: Also for that matter what is the height of the second nested form?

Comment: 3rd nested form - frm_SP: 16"?  I am uncertain how to approximate frm_SP because in 'design' mode it appears as I will never see it - like a form as opposed to a datasheet.  So I have the 'detail' section stretched down to "16" - but I don't find this in the property sheet.

Comment: 2nd nested form - frm_Stage - 10.5"?  I see my detail section stretched down to 10.5" - but I don't see the setting in the properties.  It's not near "width".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, try increasing the size of your 2nd-level form (as well as the subform control on that 2nd-level, which houses the bottom level form).

It looks like your bottom level form (with a max width of 22") requires a horizontal scroll bar in order to display within your 2nd-level form. This causes the scroll bar to appear within your 2nd-level form (where you have to scroll-- within the top form-- down in order to see it).

Instead, you probably would prefer that scroll bar to appear on your top-level form, which I believe you will get if your 2nd-level form (and the subform control for your bottom-level form) are also set to a max-width of 22".

The bottom level form will then display within the middle form without the need for a middle-form scroll bar, and the one (and only) scroll bar will render on the top form, where it will always be easily accessible without the need to scroll down first.

I have some thoughts on what causes the extra vertical white space in your second form, but I wonder if the above might not solve your problem.

Just a thought. (And I realize that this is a very old question, so perhaps you no longer need any suggestions here--in that case, I'll just leave this comment for others who may have a similar issue in the future).

Comment: Please share your thoughts. I did eventually change the data sheet form to a single form that had the 12 months in a stacked format. This seems to be working well except for the fact that the analysts naturally expect to scroll down the text boxes with the the arrow keys. I'm sure this has probably been documented already but can you point me or show me a small example of using the arrow keys to tab up and down a column of text boxes?

Comment: I think you can set up a form to scroll through a series of text boxes by enabling the "key down" event on your form and then programmatically changing the focus only if they entered key is an up or down arrow (key code 38 and 40, respectively). You'll probably want to double-check that the "tab order" attribute for all 12 text boxes is correct and sequential. 

This link should show one way to do it, but it's probably not the only way. 

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100413

Comment: With respect to the white space...Not sure if this will solve your problem, but it does remind me of an issue I had with extra white space a while back. In my case, I was getting similarly useless superfluous white space, and what I thought was a a completely superfluous (in this case, horizontal) scroll bar. After a LOT of searching with no luck, I finally discovered that the root cause was, in my case, was that my subform control was not wide enough to accommodate all of the columns in my subform, but just barely.

Comment: The default behavior seems to be that Access added roughly double the width of the underlying subform, and require that the scroll bar be able to scroll ALL the way across this roughly doubled width, rather than just scrolling the extra 1/2 centimeters that would have been required. I tried every way I could think to make my subform and subform control be formatted as *narrower*, but in my case the solution was actually to make the subform control ever so slightly *wider*.That eliminated the scroll bar completely, along with the extra white space.

Comment: Not sure if it will work in your case, but I'd at least think about making my subform control taller (as tall as possible, to start with), and seeing if that removes the extra white space. Not sure if it will work, but maybe its worth a try. Good luck!

Comment: Was any of that helpful?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to take your suggestion and try it out on my earlier versions. Even though I figured out a lot of the scrolling concepts, I'd like to see if I can learn more from your example.  You also confirmed my hunch about scrolling with the arrow keys using key down. Thanks!

Comment: I added code for arrow keys to take the place of the 'Tab' key for the 12 months were a currency value is entered.  I put the code in each of the 12 month's "On Key Down" event.  However, I can't understand why it skips January.  I have checked to make sure both the tab order as well as that there is code in the Key Down event.

Comment: I believe that, for whatever reason, the tab index numbering is meant to start at "0" rather than at "1", so just double-check to see if your first control (January, from the sound of it) is set to 0, Feb set to 1, etc. etc. Not sure if that's what's causing your issue, but it may be worth a look.

Comment: Actually, I start the functionality on the 8th Tab stop.  Since the fiscal year starts in October - it's 8, Nov - 9, etc.  Making January - the 11th tab Stop.  Have no idea why works for October - Nov then skips Dec, stopping in Jan, Feb, skipping Mar, stopping in April, May.. but it's actually sporadic unless there are values in the textboxes in which case it works perfectly.

Comment: Hmmm...now that is interesting. I am not sure what might be causing that. I'll think on that for a while and see if anything occurs to me. For the moment, I am stumped though!